# Why can't I always ask for re-authorisation in Pidgin?

Tags: authentication, pidgin

In Pidgin I sometimes have the problem, that I am not authorized to a friends account, so I cannot see his online status.

In the beginning, there is the option to "(re)-ask for authentification", but on some buddies this option is missing (using right-click on the buddy alias in the list) or at east I cannot find it any more.

How can I ask again for re-authorisation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like that is a (secret) indicator, that the buddy is not really offline, but in fact just has the status **"invisible"**.

So if you see a buddy **offline**, that is definitely online, then it is just the **status** and you are already authenticated.